# Use QML property inside a string

Tags: qt, svg, properties, qml

I've this QML object (from [this sample](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-pathsvg.html)):

```
Path {
    startX: 50; startY: 50
    PathSvg { path: "L 150 50 L 100 150 z" }
}
```

Now I want to add an attribute specifying a length, and I want to use it inside the Svg string. Something like

```
Path {
    startX: 50; startY: 50
    length: 200
    PathSvg { path: "L length 50 L 100 length z" }
}
```

How can I insert a numeric property inside a string in a QML object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

```
Path {
    id: p
    startX: 50; startY: 50
    length: 200
    PathSvg { path: "L " + p.length + " 50 L 100 " + p.length + " z" }
}
```

The good news is if the length changes, this will reevaluate and update the path string.